# SQL Server Job won't recognize AWS CLI command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, amazon-s3

Hello I have a SQL Server Job with a `CmdExec` step that goes like this:

```
powershell.exe -file D:\Script\test.ps1
```

currently the PowerShell script is simply this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://backup-sql-day/
```

and curiously the job runs sucessesfully, and there's this message.

```
The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Script\teste.ps1:1 char:1
+ aws s3 ls s3://backup-sql-day/
+ ~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aws:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException.Process

Exit Code 0.
The step succeeded.
```

So the script doesn't run, doesn't report me the error, the thing is I cannot seem to run any AWS script on the SQL Server Job, however I can run it normally with any user, does anybody have a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (unmangled) error message is actually rather self-explanatory. The script does run, but cannot find the `aws` commandline tool. Either the path to the AWS CLI installation isn't included in the `PATH` environment variable, or the SQL Server job ignores the system environment.

You can work around the issue by adding the path inside your script:

```
$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI'
aws s3 ls s3://backup-sql-day/
```

Replace `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI` with whichever folder the tool was installed to.

Comment: The thing is I installed the CLI with python command "pip install awscli" so on C:\Program Files\Amazon there is no AWSCLI folder.

Comment: @GabrielGuimarães Should've used the MSI for installing it on Windows. That doesn't change anything about what you need to do, though. Find the location of the `aws` commandline tool and add that folder to the `PATH`.

Comment: I need to change the code page (chcp 860) I needed the last version of python in order for it to work.

Comment: Just for documentation purposes this is the line I used.
$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python35\'

Comment: I had to append "bin" after the folder location to get to the "aws" command